# The Logic behind the Output

Tags: java

```
public class three {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Apfel a = new Apfel();
  }
}

class Apfel extends Frucht {
  static Print mp = new Print("Boskop!");
  Print mp2 = new Print("Gala!");

  public Apfel() {
    System.out.print("Jonagold!");
  }
}

class Frucht extends Essbar {
  Print mp2 = new Print("Banane!");

  public Frucht() {
    System.out.print("Kirsche!");
  }
}

class Essbar {
  static Print mp = new Print("Essbar!");
}

class Print {
  public Print(String msg) {
    System.out.print(msg);
  }
}
```

Can someone explain why this code prints;
"Essbar!Boskop!Banane!Kirsche!Gala!Jonagold!"

instead of printing
"Essbar!Banane!Kirsche!Boskop!Gala!Jonagold!" ?

Comment: Edited your code formatting as it was really hard to understand the code flow with the original formatting.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static variables are printed first because static variables are created on application startup, not when the code actually starts to run

> Essbar!Boskop!

Inline initialized fields are initialized next, because constructors might want to use them.

> Essbar!Boskop!Banane!Kirsche!

In-constructor initialisatons are printed last. Each construcor implicitly first calls super and then invokes its own code. Thata why "Gala!" is before "Jonagold!"

> Essbar!Boskop!Banane!Kirsche!Gala!Jonagold!

So to conclude. First static variables are printed. Those are not related to your main method at all.
Then you create `Apfel` constructor. Before this runs `Frucht` constructor is called. As `Frucht` constructor might need `Frucht.mp2`, it is created and "Banane!" is printed. `Frucht`s own constructor finishes by printing "Kirche!". Now it's time for `Apfel` constructor. As it might needs `Apfel.mp2` it is created and therefor "Gala!" is printed. Lastly the `Apfel` constructor finishes by printing "Jonagold".

As for why "Essbar!" is printed before "Boskop!". This all happens in the linking phase not running phase. Class `Essbar` needs to be visible to class `Frucht` because it extends it and `Frucht` needs to be visible to `Apfel` as it extends it. Class can not be visible to other classes before all it's static variables are initialised.